# How can i call two NSPredicate in single fetch request. Core Data iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

In my app I am using Core Data. Now I want to fetch data from database and for that I am using fetch request. But I want two use two `NSPrediate` in single fetch request so how can i do this.

This is my code:

```
let feedfetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Feed")
feedfetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userid == %@", userid)

let fetchedPerson = try moc.executeFetchRequest(feedfetch)
```

But I want to use two or more predicate so how can I do this?

I want to call all this in one fetch request so how can I do this

```
let feedfetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Feed")
feedfetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userid == %@", userid)
feedfetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "is_deleted == %@", "0")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "feed_id", ascending: false,selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
feedfetch.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let fetchedPerson = try moc.executeFetchRequest(feedfetch)
```

Comment: NSPredicate(format: "userid == \\(userId) AND is_deleted == '0'")

Comment: use AND operator like userid == %@ AND is_deleted == [NSNumber numberWithBool: FALSE] AND  .......

Comment: @LucaDavanzo cool its working well but how can i add sortDescriptior in this?

Comment: I think you can not add sort inside predicate..

Comment: You can use CompoundPredicate

Answer (score 18):

If you, for any reason, need to use two predicates(`NSPredicate` objects) instead of one line:

```
"(userid == %@) AND (is_deleted == %@)"
```

Then use `NSCompoundPredicate` API:

```
feedfetch.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type:.AndPredicate, subpredicates:[
    NSPredicate(format: "userid == %@", userid), 
    NSPredicate(format: "is_deleted == %@", "0")])
```

Comment: but how can i add NSSortDescriptor in this request? @Andriy

Comment: The same way as in your code. Sort descriptor is attached to `NSFetchRequest` not to `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching and Sorting

```
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    //Getting the cards with a video from Core Data filtered by  ("save")  and be an empity string  ("")  and by ("All")
    //Fetching from DB Card
    let savedCardRequestForVideo:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Card")

    //Creating mulit variables for filtering
    //Creating a variable "save" for filtering Core Data
    let savedCardFilterForVideo    = "save"

    //Creating a variable with an empty string "" for filtering Core Data
    let cardSortingIDForVideo      = ""

    //Creating a variable "All" for filtering Core Data
    let savedCardFilterForVideoAll = "All"

    //Creating the predicate array
     savedCardRequestForVideo.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type:.and, subpredicates:[
        NSPredicate(format: "saveVideoControl = %@", savedCardFilterForVideo),
        NSPredicate(format: "cardSortingID = %@", cardSortingIDForVideo),
        NSPredicate(format: "allData == %@", savedCardFilterForVideoAll)])


    //Here we are sorting the reuslts in a ascending order
    let savedSortDescriptorForVideo                = NSSortDescriptor(key: "businessName", ascending: ascendingOrDescending)
        savedCardRequestForVideo.sortDescriptors   = [savedSortDescriptorForVideo]

    //Creating a variable to hold the results that are being fetched
    let savedCardFilterResultsFoeVideo             = try! context.fetch(savedCardRequestForVideo) as! [NSManagedObject]

    //The variable savedCardsForVideo will hold the results array
    savedCardsForVideo  = savedCardFilterResultsFoeVideo  //This ia an Array<AnyObject>
```